# Syncing UI Thread and workhorse thread

Tags: android, multithreading

Hi so I have 1 thread which uses a surfaceview to draw to the screen then another thread updating the positions of objects on the screen. How do I make these run at the same speed?

Comment: What do you mean *at same speed*?

Comment: I want to update the object positions at the speed in which they are drawn

Comment: Then update the positions in the drawing thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a trade off:

- You want to update that screen sufficiently often that all motion appears smooth.
- You want to give as much CPU as possible to the workhorse thread

The easy solution is something like this:

1. The work horse thread sets a flag indicating when there has been change worthy of a redraw.
2. The UI thread has a flow a bit like this

   ```
   do {
       renderScreen();
       while (!screenNeedsRedrawing) {
           Thread.sleep(10);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Don't mean to be critical, but sleeping for a short period of time isn't a good idea. You force too many context switches for the OS, dragging down performance for your app. It would probably be better to use a synchronized object where you would replace the while loop with waitObject.wait() and after the worker thread is finished it will call waitObject.notifyAll() which will allow the render thread to continue. With this in place, the OS won't bother bringing your UI thread to the foreground at all until work is all done. With sleep it will repetitively try to and have to put it back.

Comment: I've been thinking about your comment and, although I would generally agree with you that one only wants to wake a sleeping thread when it really has something to do, when the thread is doing the screen rendering in a game, it should really do something at a minimum FPS rate. So, perhaps 10 is too short, but 100 would be too long - the screen would only re-render every 10th of a second, which would be a poor user experience. Perhaps 25 (40Hz) would be a good compromise?

Comment: You make a good point and 25 seems like it would be a good compromise.  It would probably take some experimenting to find a good number. I personally like using wait handles to synchronize, since it will wake it only when it's ready.

Comment: As a general rule, I would absolutely agree with you - threads with intermittent activity should only be active when they have to, and time based polling is generally second best for this. However, in the context of screen rendering, I prefer to think of the screen rendering thread being the "dominant" thread which should re-render at a minimum rate for user experience: the other threads can have as much of the remaining time as they need, and if they need less, can allow an extra render cycle.

Answer (score 1):

its very simple, just create a callback to the main thread using handlers or the method `runOnUiThread` and update the UI from the worker thread whenever you want it to update

Answer (score 1):

Use an OS [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

You have to create the handler on the context of the worker thread, then call .post() with the runnable you want to call. Do this every time you draw and it will post the update stuff on the worker thread.  Now you may want to lock the drawing thread until the updating is complete in which case you would want something like a thread-safe variable to force the draw thread to wait for the update to finish.